# WriteUTF cannot be applied to (int)

Tags: java

```
for (Account accountObj : accounts) {
                System.out.print(accountObj);
                account.writeUTF(accountObj.getAccountHolderName());
                account.writeUTF(accountObj.getAccountType());
                account.writeUTF(accountObj.getBalance());
                account.writeUTF(accountObj.getAccountNumber());

            }
```

'writeUTF(java.lang.String)' in 'java.io.DataOutputStream' cannot be applied to '(double)'
'writeUTF(java.lang.String)' in 'java.io.DataOutputStream' cannot be applied to '(int)'

so, I got these two errors, and I even tried parseInt and double before storing the values in the ArrayList yet, am a little confused, some help would be kind : )

Comment: `writeUTF` expects a string, you're trying to write an int. Either you need to convert the int to string, or you need to use one of the other methods. As an aside, are you really sure you should be using `DataOutputStream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [the docs of that class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#method_summary), you can see that each type has its own method for writing it to the `DataOutputStream`.

That means to write a `double`, use the `writeDouble` method and the `writeInt` method for `int` values.

The `UTF` in `writeUTF(String)` hint at the fact that the `String` will be written to the stream in a specific encoding. A UTF encoding only makes sense for writing `String`s.